# The error message indicates a dependency conflict related to the versions of React and Material-UI being used

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-package

```
Log files:
C:\Users\mahes\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-11T14_48_13_184Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: travel_advisor@0.1.0
Found: react@18.2.0
node_modules/react
  react@"^18.2.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
node_modules/@material-ui/core
  @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to install dependencies but it is giving me an error. I have LTS version of node module